# How do I create a JSONObject?

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I'm trying to "create" a JSONObject. Right now I'm using JSON-Simple and I'm trying to do something along the lines of this (sorry if any typo's are made in this example JSON file)

```
{
    "valuedata": {
        "period": 1,
        "icon": "pretty"
    }
}
```

Right now I'm having issues finding on how to write valuedata into a JSON file through Java, what I did try was:

```
Map<String, String> t = new HashMap<String, String>();
t.put("Testing", "testing");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(t);
```

but that just did

```
{
    "Testing": "testing"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatr you want to do is put another JSONObject inside your JSONObject "jsonObject", in the field "valuedata" to be more exact. You can do this like that...

```
// Create empty JSONObect here: "{}"
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

// Create another empty JSONObect here: "{}"
JSONObject myValueData = new JSONObject();

// Now put the 2nd JSONObject into the field "valuedata" of the first:
// { "valuedata" : {} }
jsonObject.put("valuedata", myValueData);

// And now add all your fields for your 2nd JSONObject, for example period:
// { "valuedata" : { "period" : 1} }
myValueData.put("period", 1);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Following is example which shows JSON object streaming using Java JSONObject:
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

class JsonEncodeDemo 
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

      obj.put("name","foo");
      obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
      obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
      obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));

      StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
      obj.writeJSONString(out);
      
      String jsonText = out.toString();
      System.out.print(jsonText);
   }
}
While compile and executing above program, this will produce following result:
{"balance": 1000.21, "num":100, "is_vip":true, "name":"foo"}
```

Comment: Perhaps you might want to edit your code tags a little bit, as the code snippet contains your text and will not run ;-)